# R: A facet_wrap() without a factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to create a matrix of histograms with `ggplot` and `facet_wrap()`. More or less the code I have is the following:

```
df_3<-data.frame(rnorm(1000),...,rnorm(1000))
#The data frame has 1000 observations and 16 variables.

colnames(df_3) <- letters[1:16]

library(ggplot2)
gr12 <- ggplot(df_3, aes(x=observations)) + geom_histogram()
```

My question is: how can I do to plot the matrix of histograms with `facet_wrap()` and without a factor variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Melt the dataframe into a long format (see `reshape2`), thus your data frame goes from being

```
    a   b   c ...    p
1 0.1 0.2 0.3 ... 0.16
2 0.1 0.1 0.2 ... 0.00
```

(My internal randomizer is really bad.)
to

```
variable  value
      a    0.1
      b    0.2
      c    0.3
    ...    ...
      p   0.16
      a    0.1
      b    0.1
      c    0.2
    ...    ...
      p   0.00
```

Then `variable` is your factor that you wish to facet by. If the long formatted data frame is `df_4`, I imagine you could do

```
ggplot(df_4, aes(x=value)) + stat_histogram() + facet_wrap(variable)
```